# AWS Docker Container for Local Development

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm using AWS Dynamo DB, Lambda, ElastichSearch, ElasticCache(Redis). I want to bring all these services offline for local development. I wonder's is there a Docker container for all these services?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps! There's a (set of) Docker containers that claim they provide local implementations of popular AWS services: [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack).

*Edit*: For lambda specific things there's also [Docker Lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda)!

I've never actually used these Docker containers, but have wanted to. (But my development needs try to use commodity services instead of vendor specific. So MongoDB instead of DynoDB, and sure we might use ElastiCache to run our Redis cluster, but that just means in local development we can use Redis directly. Having said that, that's not everyone's cup of tea / maybe not possible for some things..)

Answer (score 2):

We use docker for most AWS Services for local development except for AWS Lambda.

We use the service containers as below:

- [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/) for RDS MySQL
- [Redis](https://github.com/docker-library/redis) for ElastiCache
- [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker) for AWS ElasticSearch
- [fake-s3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) for S3
- [ActiveMQ](https://hub.docker.com/r/webcenter/activemq/) for mocking SQS and SNS topics (The implementation for SNS topics is a bit ugly, but abstracted out in one place with some if-else statements)

Most of our services make use docker-compose to start the dependent containers. We've included these containers on our build server too to run our integration tests.

In addition, most of the containers we are using needed some modifications to the original Docker file. So we had to push our changes to our own Docker repository, which we maintain using ECS.

For Lambda, we do not use a docker container as we start our own HTTP server locally to test and invoke the lambda function.

Been using this setup for over a year without any issues. You may also want to refer to [this](http://engineering.ifttt.com/oss/2015/10/06/developing-with-docker/) blog from IFTTT to get some more ideas around DNS resolution and how to make this effort better.

Comment: What do you use for SNS?

Comment: ActiveMQ itself.

Comment: What do you use for testing elasticache in cluster-enabled mode?